# Why FULLTEXT index is not being populated - MYSQL

Tags: sql, mysql, full-text-search

I am trying to add a fulltext index against a table, but it does not seem to apply.

```
ADD FULLTEXT `genre` (
`genre`
)
```

The query executes, but the cardinality remains at just 1 (even though i ahve a few thousand records)

I tried ANALYZE, REPAIR and neither seemed to update the index.  If I create a regular index the cardinality is updated immediately.

A select against the index returns ans empty set, even though i know of matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cardinality has little sense for `FULLTEXT` indexes, since one record can be referenced by multiple keys (one key per word).

A `FULLTEXT` index will always be used for the query if it's applicable at all:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    genre
WHERE   MATCH(genre) AGAINST ('mystring')
```

The index, though, will not index the words less than `ft_min_word_len` characters long (which is `4` by default), and hence the query will not match them.

Could you please post the query which you think should work but it doesn't?

Comment: Bingo.  My matching row only had 3 words. I just switched to using LIKE on a INDEX and the performance difference is negligible.

Thank!

Comment: `@Eddie`: you can also change `ft_min_word_len` in `MySQL` settings.